# Form nested JSON object array from given JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json array of the form

```
[{'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'100','op':'cr'},
{'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'200','op':'dr'},
{'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'300','op':'cr'},
{'from':'c','to':'d','type':'sub','value':'400','op':'dr'},
{'from':'c','to':'d','type':'sub','value':'500','op':'cr'}]
```

I want the output as

```
[{'from':'a','to':'b','add':[{'100':'cr'},{'200':'dr'},{'300':'cr'}]},
 {'from':'c','to':'d','sub':[{'400':'dr'},{'500':'cr'}]}]
```

How to do it in Javascript/NodeJS?

Comment: There is no magic way to do this, you will need to write your own algo. Please show use what you may have tried, and any issues you are facing.

Comment: you'd best work with javascript objects, JSON strings would be tricky to work with ... `How to do it in Javascript?` - by writing some code - this isn't icanhazcode.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object as hash table and assign the values via the key with parts from `from` and `to`.

```js
var data = [{ from: 'a', to: 'b', option: '100' }, { from: 'a', to: 'b', option: '200' }, { from: 'a', to: 'b', option: '300' }, { from: 'c', to: 'd', option: '400' }, { from: 'c', to: 'd', option: '500' }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = [a.from, a.to].join('|');
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = { from: a.from, to: a.to, option: [] };
        grouped.push(this[key]);
    }
    this[key].option.push(a.option);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wqkhms3/1/

```js
var data = [{'from':'a','to':'b','option':'100'},
    {'from':'a','to':'b','option':'200'},
    {'from':'a','to':'b','option':'300'},
    {'from':'c','to':'d','option':'400'},
    {'from':'c','to':'d','option':'500'}];
    
    var out = [];
    
    // Utility function which finds-out if this object is available in the RESULT array or not
    function findObj(list, item) {
      var resultObj;
      for (var i in list) {
        if (list[i].from === item.from && list[i].to === item.to) {
          resultObj = list[i];
          break;
        }
      }
    
      return resultObj;
    }
    
    // EXECUTION
    for (var i in data) {

      // Check if this objec is available in the RESULT array,
      if (findObj(out, data[i])) {

        // If yes, then push the value to it
        findObj(out, data[i]).option.push(data[i].option);
      } else {
        // If NO, then add this item to the RESULT array
        out.push({
          from: data[i].from,
          to: data[i].to,
          option: [data[i].option]
        });
      }
    }
    
    console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet -

```
'use strict';
var x = [{ 'from': 'a', 'to': 'b', 'option': '100' },
  { 'from': 'a', 'to': 'b', 'option': '200' },
  { 'from': 'a', 'to': 'b', 'option': '300' },
  { 'from': 'c', 'to': 'd', 'option': '400' },
  { 'from': 'c', 'to': 'd', 'option': '500' }
];

var match = false;

x.reduce(function(returnVal, item) {
  match = false;
  returnVal.map(function(each) {
    if (each.from === item.from && each.to === item.to) {
      if (Array.isArray(each.option)) {
        each.option.push(item.option);
      } else {
        each.option = [each.option];
        each.option.push(item.option);
      }
      match = true;
    }
    return each;
  })
  if (!match) {
    returnVal.push(item);
  }
  return returnVal;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [
    {'from':'a','to':'b','option':'100'},
    {'from':'a','to':'b','option':'200'},
    {'from':'a','to':'b','option':'300'},
    {'from':'c','to':'d','option':'400'},
    {'from':'c','to':'d','option':'500'}
];

var array2 = [];

for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    var obj = null,
        from = array1[i]['from'], 
        to = array1[i]['to'];

    for(var j=0; j<array2.length; j++) {
        if (array2[j]['from'] == from && array2[j]['to'] == to) {
            obj = array2[j];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (obj == null) {
        obj = {'from':from,'to':to,'option':[]};
        array2.push(obj);
    }

    obj['option'].push(array1[i]['option']);
}

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: I suggest you to break loop after obj = array2[j];

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple loop to iterate through keys in a 'tmp' object which combined from 'from' and 'to' may help:

```
            var input = [{'from':'a','to':'b','option':'100'},
                        {'from':'a','to':'b','option':'200'},
                        {'from':'a','to':'b','option':'300'},
                        {'from':'c','to':'d','option':'400'},
                        { 'from': 'c', 'to': 'd', 'option': '500' }];
            var tmp = {};
            $.each(input, function (idx, obj) {
                var key = obj.from + obj.to
                tmp[key] = tmp[key] || { from: obj.from, to: obj.to};
                tmp[key].option = tmp[key].option || [];
                tmp[key].option.push(obj.option);
            });
            var output = [];
            for(var key in tmp)
            {
                output.push(tmp[key]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout jQuery, only javascript and cross browswer:

```js
var array = [
 {
  'from': 'a',
  'to': 'b',
  'option': '100'
 },
 {
  'from': 'a',
  'to': 'b',
  'option': '200'
 },
 {
  'from': 'a',
  'to': 'b',
  'option': '300'
 },
 {
  'from': 'c',
  'to': 'd',
  'option': '400'
 },
 {
  'from': 'c',
  'to': 'd',
  'option': '500'
 }
];

var array2 = [];
for (var a in array) {
 for (var b in array2) {
  if (array2[b].from == array[a].from && array2[b].to == array[a].to) {
   array2[b].option.push(array[a].option);
   break;
  }
 }
 
 if (!array2[b] || array2[b].option.indexOf(array[a].option) == -1) {
  array2.push({
   from: array[a].from,
   to: array[a].to,
   option: [array[a].option]
  });
 }
}

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function unique to get the unique array out of the given array.

```
var array1 = [
{'from':'a','to':'b','option':'100'},
{'from':'a','to':'b','option':'200'},
{'from':'a','to':'b','option':'300'},
{'from':'c','to':'d','option':'400'},
{'from':'c','to':'d','option':'500'}
];


function unique(array) {
    var i = 0,
        map = {}, // This map object stores the objects of array1 uniquely
        uniqueArray = [],
        obj,
        len = array.length;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       obj = array[i];
       from = obj.from; to = obj.to;
       // Create an id using from and to of the object
       id = from + '-' + to;
       // Check if object is already there in map object
       if (map[id]) {
            // If options is not an array then store the options in array
            map[id].option = map[id].option instanceof Array ? map[id].option : [map[id].option];
            map[id].option.push(obj.option);
       }
      // If object not available in map then create an object
       else {

            map[id] = {};
            map[id].from = obj.from;
            map[id].to = obj.to;
            map[id].option = obj.option;
            // Pushing the map object to the unique array
            uniqueArray.push(map[id]);
       }

    }
    return uniqueArray;
}
```